# Create instance of form trought Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#

Hello I would like to found solution of my problem,i found there is method from .net Activator.CreateInstance but I realy dont understand now why it didnt work form me..

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    OpenFormInPanel(object name_of_form,Control panel....,);


}

private void OpenFormInPanel(object name_of_form,Control panel....,)
{
      var objForm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("WindowsFormsApp12.Form2"), 1, "test");
        //   Form2 objForm = new Form2();
        // Form objForm = (Form)handle.Unwrap();
        //ObjectHandle objForm = Activator.CreateInstance("Namespace.Forms", "Form2");

        objForm.TopLevel = false;
        panel1.Controls.Add(objForm);
        objForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        objForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        objForm.Show();
}
```

This is Form2

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp12
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Im thanks full for every help.

Comment: What doesn't work?  Out of curiosity, why are you doing this (not that there's anything wrong with it)?

Comment: System.MissingMethodException: The WindowsFormsApp12.Form2 constructor was not found.

Comment: I want to create "framework" for app that if i click on toolstrip then it will open this form in panel on main form

Comment: and I would like to have methot for this.

Comment: Do you have a Form2 class within the WindowsFormsApp12?  What does its constructor look like (perhaps you could show us some of your Form2 code, including the namespace, the class declaration and the constructor)?  There are a whole bunch of `Activator.CreateInstance` overloads, what do your last two parameters signify?

Comment: I did update of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Activator.CreateInstance` is a way of creating a class instance using a `Type`. If you know exactly which type you need to create then there's probably no reason to use it.

You could just do this:

```
var objForm = new Form2();
```

`CreateInstance` is really just doing the same thing - it's calling the constructor.

The [overload you're calling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Object___) is going to take the other arguments and try to pass them to the constructor. So this:

```
var objForm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("WindowsFormsApp12.Form2"), 1, "test");
```

is basically the same as this:

```
var objForm = new Form2(1, "test");
```

If you try typing that in your application you'll probably see a compile error because `Form2` doesn't have a constructor that takes an integer and a string `(1, "test")`. That's probably why it's failing. It's trying to call a constructor that doesn't exist.

---

While I was typing this detail was added in the comments:

> System.MissingMethodException: The WindowsFormsApp12.Form2 constructor was not found

If you go to the link to that method (it's linked above) it tells you the different exceptions that it might throw and why.

It says:

> #### MissingMethodException
>
> In the .NET for Windows Store apps or the Portable Class Library, catch the base class exception, MissingMemberException, instead.
>
> **No matching public constructor was found.**

So that's exactly it. It's trying to call a constructor that takes an integer and a string but the class doesn't have one.

Unless you definitely need to use `Activator.CreateInstance` I wouldn't try fixing the way you use it. I would just call the constructor the "normal" way. Or maybe start with that, get it working, and then if you need `CreateInstance` change it back to that once you know which constructor you want to call.

That's a handy tool that a lot of developers don't use. If you're calling a method of class in the .NET Framework and it either throws an exception and you don't know why, or you want to know what exceptions it might throw, you can go to the documentation for that method and it will usually tell you what exceptions it throws and why. You can usually just highlight the method in your code and press F1.